# Python script gets stuck running without error after adding some lines to script

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

After adding lines 10 to 56 (SECTION DELETE OBSOLETE UPC AND NO UPC AND NO PRICE ITEMS), the python script won't execute or it is executing but can't finish and CMDER shows no error, and gets jammed as the only way is to exit CMDer with force shut down.

[image]

Below is in .py, not in .html despite code in html  snippet

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter

# Load the workbook
workbook = load_workbook('item.xlsx')

# Select the active sheet (first sheet by default)
sheet = workbook.active

# * - SECTION DELETE OBSOLETE UPC AND NO UPC AND NO PRICE ITEMS - *

# Get the column names
columns9 = [cell.value for cell in next(sheet.iter_rows(min_row=1))]

# Variable to track if a non-blank "Item Code" row has been encountered
non_blank_row_encountered = False

# Iterate through the rows in reverse order to avoid index issues
for row in reversed(list(sheet.iter_rows(min_row=2))):
    item_code9 = row[columns9.index('Item Code')].value
    barcode9 = row[columns9.index('Barcode (row 1 for current use) (Barcodes)')].value
    barcode_type9 = row[columns9.index('Barcode Type (Barcodes)')].value
    selling_price = row[columns9.index('SELLING PRICE *(Fetched from Selling Price List)*')].value

    if item_code9 is not None and (barcode9 is None or selling_price is None or selling_price == 0):
        sheet.delete_rows(row[0].row)
        non_blank_row_encountered = True
    elif item_code9 is None and non_blank_row_encountered:
        sheet.delete_rows(row[0].row)

    if (
        item_code9 is not None
        and selling_price is not None
        and barcode_type9 == "Obsolete"
    ):
        # Delete rows below if they are "Obsolete" or blank
        current_row_index = row[0].row
        next_row_index = current_row_index + 1
        next_row_item_code9 = sheet.cell(row=next_row_index, column=columns9.index('Item Code') + 1).value

        while next_row_item_code9 is None or next_row_item_code9 == "Obsolete":
            sheet.delete_rows(next_row_index)
            next_row_item_code9 = sheet.cell(row=next_row_index, column=columns9.index('Item Code') + 1).value

        sheet.delete_rows(current_row_index)

    elif item_code9 is not None and selling_price is not None and barcode_type9 == "Obsolete":
        # Delete row if the row below the Item Code is not blank
        next_row_index = row[0].row + 1
        next_row_item_code9 = sheet.cell(row=next_row_index, column=columns9.index('Item Code') + 1).value

        if next_row_item_code9 is not None:
            sheet.delete_rows(row[0].row)

# Save the modified workbook
workbook.save('delete7.xlsx')

# * - SECTION BARCODES TYPE SEPARATION - *

# Load the workbook
workbook = load_workbook('delete7.xlsx')

# Select the active sheet (first sheet by default)
sheet = workbook.active

# Find the column index for the "Barcode Type (Barcodes)" column
barcodetype_column_index = None
for column in sheet.iter_cols():
    if column[0].value == "Barcode Type (Barcodes)":
        barcodetype_column_index = column[0].column
        break

if barcodetype_column_index is None:
    print("Barcode Type (Barcodes) column not found!")
    exit()

# Find the column index for the "Barcode (row 1 for current use) (Barcodes)" column
barcode_column_index = None
for column in sheet.iter_cols():
    if column[0].value == "Barcode (row 1 for current use) (Barcodes)":
        barcode_column_index = column[0].column
        break

if barcode_column_index is None:
    print("Barcode (row 1 for current use) (Barcodes) column not found!")
    exit()

# Get all unique non-blank values except "Obsolete" from the "Barcode Type (Barcodes)" column
barcodetypes = set()
for cell in sheet[get_column_letter(barcodetype_column_index)][1:]:
    if cell.value is not None and cell.value != "" and cell.value != "Obsolete":
        barcodetypes.add(cell.value)

# Create new columns next to the "barcodetype" column and copy values from the "Barcode (row 1 for current use) (Barcodes)" column
new_columns = []
column_index = barcodetype_column_index + 1

# Check if "UPC-A" column exists
if "UPC-A" in barcodetypes:
    # Insert "UPC-A" column first
    column_letter = get_column_letter(column_index)
    sheet.insert_cols(column_index)
    sheet[column_letter + '1'] = "UPC-A_py"  # Add suffix "_py" to the new column header

    # Copy values from the "Barcode (row 1 for current use) (Barcodes)" column
    for row in range(2, sheet.max_row + 1):
        barcode_value = sheet[get_column_letter(barcode_column_index) + str(row)].value
        barcodetype_value = sheet[get_column_letter(barcodetype_column_index) + str(row)].value

        if barcodetype_value == "UPC-A":
            sheet[column_letter + str(row)] = barcode_value

    new_columns.append(column_letter)
    column_index += 1

# Insert other barcode type columns
for barcodetype in barcodetypes:
    if barcodetype != "UPC-A":
        column_letter = get_column_letter(column_index)
        sheet.insert_cols(column_index)
        sheet[column_letter + '1'] = barcodetype + "_py"  # Add suffix "_py" to the new column header

        # Copy values from the "Barcode (row 1 for current use) (Barcodes)" column
        for row in range(2, sheet.max_row + 1):
            barcode_value = sheet[get_column_letter(barcode_column_index) + str(row)].value
            barcodetype_value = sheet[get_column_letter(barcodetype_column_index) + str(row)].value

            if barcodetype_value == barcodetype:
                sheet[column_letter + str(row)] = barcode_value

        new_columns.append(column_letter)
        column_index += 1

# Update matching values in the "Barcode Type (Barcodes)" column with suffix "_py"
for row in range(2, sheet.max_row + 1):
    barcodetype_value = sheet[get_column_letter(barcodetype_column_index) + str(row)].value

    if barcodetype_value in barcodetypes:
        updated_value = barcodetype_value 
        sheet[get_column_letter(barcodetype_column_index) + str(row)].value = updated_value

# Delete the "Barcode Type (Barcodes)" column
sheet.delete_cols(barcodetype_column_index)

# Delete the "Barcode (row 1 for current use) (Barcodes)" column
sheet.delete_cols(barcode_column_index)

# * - SECTION SUPPLIER ABBREVIATIONS CONSOLIDATION - *

# Find the column index of "Supplier Abbr. (Supplier Items)"
header_row = 1
supplier_abbr_column = None
for column in range(1, sheet.max_column + 1):
    header_value = sheet.cell(row=header_row, column=column).value
    if header_value == "Supplier Abbr. (Supplier Items)":
        supplier_abbr_column = column
        break

# If the "Supplier Abbr. (Supplier Items)" column is found, proceed with modification
if supplier_abbr_column is not None:
    # Find the last column index
    last_column = sheet.max_column

    # Insert a new column "Supplier_py" to the right of "Supplier Abbr. (Supplier Items)"
    new_column_index = supplier_abbr_column + 1
    sheet.insert_cols(new_column_index)

    # Update the header for the new column
    sheet.cell(row=header_row, column=new_column_index, value="Supplier_py")

    # Iterate over each row in the sheet
    for row in range(2, sheet.max_row + 1):
        item_code = sheet.cell(row=row, column=1).value
        supplier_abbr = sheet.cell(row=row, column=supplier_abbr_column).value

        if item_code and supplier_abbr:
            supplier_py = supplier_abbr
            current_row = row + 1

            # Fetch the values from the following rows until the next non-blank row in both columns
            while current_row <= sheet.max_row:
                current_item_code = sheet.cell(row=current_row, column=1).value
                current_supplier_abbr = sheet.cell(row=current_row, column=supplier_abbr_column).value

                if current_item_code and current_supplier_abbr:
                    break

                if current_supplier_abbr:
                    supplier_py += " " + current_supplier_abbr

                current_row += 1

            # Set the value in the "Supplier_py" column
            sheet.cell(row=row, column=new_column_index, value=supplier_py)

    # Remove the "Supplier Abbr. (Supplier Items)" column
    sheet.delete_cols(supplier_abbr_column)

# * - SECTION CODE MEDICAMENT SEPERATION - *

# Get the header values from the columns A_py, B_py, D_py, X_py, H_py, and E_py
headers = [sheet.cell(row=1, column=column_index).value for column_index in range(1, sheet.max_column + 1)]

# Find the index of the "Code list (Code Médicament)" column
code_column_index = headers.index('Code list (Code Médicament)') + 1
item_column_index = headers.index('Item Code') + 1

# Insert new columns A_py, B_py, D_py, X_py, H_py, and E_py adjacent to the "Item Code" column
sheet.insert_cols(code_column_index + 1, 6)

# Update the headers list to include the new columns
headers = headers[:code_column_index] + ['A_py', 'B_py', 'D_py', 'X_py', 'H_py', 'E_py'] + headers[code_column_index:]

# Set the header values for the new columns
for column_index, header_value in enumerate(headers, start=1):
    sheet.cell(row=1, column=column_index).value = header_value

# Iterate over each row starting from the second row
for row in range(2, sheet.max_row + 1):
    code_value = sheet.cell(row=row, column=code_column_index).value
    item_value = sheet.cell(row=row, column=item_column_index).value

    if item_value is not None:
        # Iterate over the header columns (excluding the "Code" column)
        for column_index in range(1, sheet.max_column + 1):
            if column_index != code_column_index:
                header_value = sheet.cell(row=1, column=column_index).value

                # Check if the code value is not None and the header matches the code value + "_py"
                if code_value is not None and header_value == code_value + "_py":
                    # Copy the code value to the respective column in the same row
                    sheet.cell(row=row, column=column_index).value = code_value
    else:
        # Find the nearest non-blank row above
        nearest_row = row - 1
        while nearest_row > 1 and sheet.cell(row=nearest_row, column=item_column_index).value is None:
            nearest_row -= 1

        # Iterate over the header columns (excluding the "Code" column)
        for column_index in range(1, sheet.max_column + 1):
            if column_index != code_column_index:
                header_value = sheet.cell(row=1, column=column_index).value

                # Check if the code value is not None and the header matches the code value + "_py"
                if code_value is not None and header_value == code_value + "_py":
                    # Copy the code value to the respective column in the nearest non-blank row above
                    sheet.cell(row=nearest_row, column=column_index).value = code_value

# Remove the "Code" column
sheet.delete_cols(code_column_index)

# * - SECTION REMOVE EMPTY ROWS - *

# Create a list to store the row indices that should be deleted
rows_to_delete = []

# Iterate over each row starting from the second row
for row in range(2, sheet.max_row + 1):
    # Check if all values in the row are blank
    is_blank_row = all(sheet.cell(row=row, column=column_index).value is None for column_index in range(1, sheet.max_column + 1))

    if is_blank_row:
        rows_to_delete.append(row)

# Iterate over the rows in reverse order and delete them
for row in reversed(rows_to_delete):
    sheet.delete_rows(row)

# Save the modified workbook
workbook.save('Upload for Barcodes3.xlsx')
```

Comment: Hey mate, try to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also, you may want to separate your code into functions, it's gonna help you (and us) figure everything out quicker, and make the program easier to maintain.

Comment: @Yarin_007 thank you. unfortunately, i started to learn how to code last week haha, there is so much to learn! but yeah, you are correct. but I can't figure out what went wrong, because each section of the code works, but when put together , they don't.. if i remove the SECTION DELETE OBSOLETE UPC AND NO UPC AND NO PRICE ITEMS, it works. but if i use the SECTION DELETE OBSOLETE UPC AND NO UPC AND NO PRICE ITEMS alone, it also works, but together , it doesn't.

Comment: so the problem is into those 3 lines:

"while next_row_item_code9 is None or next_row_item_code9 == "Obsolete":
            sheet.delete_rows(next_row_index)
            next_row_item_code9 = sheet.cell(row=next_row_index, column=columns9.index('Item Code') + 1).value"

Not sure what's wrong with the code

Comment: Well, the 'while` clause is probably always true. It's true if `next_row_item_code9` is either "Obsolete" or `None`.

Comment: @Yarin_007 thanks! do you know how do i correct it? I mean is it a logical error or it's a syntax error, or should I remove the while clause or can it be replaced? thanks!!

Comment: You haven't created a minimal reproducible example. Please attach an example xlsx file.  Or, inside the loop print the value of `next_row_item_code9` and figure out why the while clause is wrong. my guess is if "next_row_item_code9" is `None` you should exit the loop. *Also*, note the difference between "empty string" ('') and "Nothing" (None).